# Having some trouble with echo '' | tr -d '' bash command

Tags: bash, shell, applescript, echo, tr

I've been using this script on smaller files and it works just fine. But when I went up to a file with about 6,000 records, it started giving me the error of "The command exited with a non-zero status."

```
set csvfile to (choose file with prompt "Please choose a CSV:" of type "csv")
set the_read_csv to (read csvfile)
set non_standard_chars to (do shell script "echo " & quoted form of the_read_csv & " | tr -d '[:alpha:]''[:cntrl:]''[:space:]''[:digit:]''[:punct:]'")
```

Is there a limit to `echo` command? Or is there an easier way to do this? I'm basically trying to check the file for Non-ASCII characters via shell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `echo` and a giant string when you can use `cat` with the filename.  Better yet, just use a redirect so that `tr` is getting its input directly from the file:

```
set non_standard_chars to (¬
  do shell script "tr -d '[:alpha:][:cntrl:][:space:][:digit:][:punct:]' <" & ¬
      quoted form of POSIX path of csvfile ¬
)
```

Comment: But this won't replace my file right? I just want to see what might be there if anything

Comment: it doesn't replace the file.  Just as in your original code, the output is the non-ASCII characters in the file, which is still there. You're just telling the shell to read from the file itself, instead of your applescript code reading the file and passing it as one big string to `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> I'm basically trying to check the file for Non-ASCII characters

the next:

```
perl -pe 's/[[:ascii:]]//g;' <<EOF
asciiáščíí
EOF
```

removes all ascii chars, so prints non-ascii

```
áščíí
```

for the file run

```
perl -pe 's/[[:ascii:]]//g;'  filename
#or
perl -pe 's/[[:ascii:]]//g;'  < filename
#or
something | perl -pe 's/[[:ascii:]]//g;'
```

And the

```
perl -pe 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g;'
```

will removes all non-ascii and prints only ascii

```
ascii
```

Comment: Well what I want is to display those Non-ASCII chars. By running the `tr` and deleting out all normal chars, I'm then left with those non-ASCII chars. Hence the `tr -d` and all alpha, cntrl, etc. If what it displays is blank, then I know there are none in that file.

Comment: Oh, I see.. I'm not as familiar with `perl` sorry. How would I get file in there to read it?

Comment: The fact that it's Perl instead of tr doesn't change how you get input to it.  So you could `do shell script "perl whatever <" & quoted form of posix path of filename.`  But you could also do `do shell script "(perl or tr or something) <<EOF" & linefeed & the_read_csv && linefeed && "EOF"`

Comment: @double_j ahhh sorry - i somewhat missed the "applescript" part.. ;) But you can use the perl script directly in the Automator ("Run shell script") and select "perl" as shell.

Comment: That's cool though! I can still use this, the only "Applescript" part is just what I'm running the bash script through cause I just make automated scripts. I didn't know about the whole part of how to get file in there so that helps a lot!